# Secure whole site except login page

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I want to have whole site secured through login with FOSUserBundle.
I tried to set security.yml like this:

```
 firewalls:
   login:
        pattern: ^/login
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

   main:
        pattern: ^/ 
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
```

But then I don't know what to set in config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: My\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Whatever I try I can't login, or still get errors like:

> You must configure the check path to be handled by the firewall using
>   form_login in your security firewall configuration.

EDIT: Second response from here seems to work:
[Symfony 2 - firewall and access control issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649527/symfony-2-firewall-and-access-control-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login firewall accidentally entails `login_check` which should reside in the main firewall. You don't have to change anything in your configuration except one thing in your login firewall:

```
firewalls:
    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
```

If you don't notice, there is a $ at the end, which makes sure only the path `/login` is matched, but not paths like `/login_check`.

The access_control and changes @Patt suggests are not neccesary.

Comment: @Patt It's easy to miss. But once you spent half an hour looking for the problem, the solution sticks ;)

Comment: Nice. I have finally used the answer which I had linked in post but good to know that the login_check should be included inside main route.