# Image management for styles in Symfony2

Tags: image, symfony, assets

Ok now it is time to make my webpage look pretty but when I try to include images in my twig templates this images do not show.

My images are stored in the route `'MyBundle/Resources/public/images'`

and im trying to use them in the twig templates like

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/predit/images/goddie.png') }}">
```

or in the `<style>` like

```
{
 background-image:url('gradient.png');
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Any idea? I'm kinda new in web styling and I'm using Symfony as framework

Comment: do you have any security firewalls configured in symfony?

Comment: I have one but nothing related to images

Comment: yep, but you might need to allow access to the images by something like `- { path: ^/images, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }` and `anonymous: ~`

Comment: see this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649527/symfony-2-firewall-and-access-control-issue

Comment: It is not working. I think it is not a firewall problem. I guess it is more syntax or routing the images properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php app/console assets:install web
```

After that look the path to your files in your web folder and set it in the asset. 
It should be something like "bundles/yourBundleName/images/goddie.png"

Comment: That was the answer. Thank you. Moreover the name of the file was incorrect, my bad.